# JAX-RS Web Service Working through browser but not through XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jax-rs

I wrote the JAX-RS Service for downloading file with apache server:

The main content of service is-

```
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response convertCtoF() {

     String path = "D:\\a.pdf";
     File file=new File(path);
     ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok((Object) file);
        rb.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=a.pdf");
        return rb.build();
}
```

This is working when i am accessing it through web browser.

But when I am accessing through XMLHTTPRequest it is not working. It gives **XMLHttp.Status=0**

Client Side Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Download()
{

 var  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();


xmlhttp.open('GET','http://localhost:8080/RESTExample/ABC/ctofservice',true);



xmlhttp.send();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {


               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                alert('xmlhttp.readyState == 4');

                  if ( xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                        alert('xmlhttp.status == 200');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    alert(xmlhttp.status);
                  }

                  }
                 }


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>File Downloading Web Interface</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="Download()">Download File</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with XMLHTTPRequest because you are downloading a file and for security reasons you are not allowed to do that with Ajax. There are various workarounds to try out. I will not duplicate those here, so try searching for "ajax file download" on Google, then choose your preffered approach.